# Submit slider value from Ajax using JQuery null

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to pass value slider to controller using ajax and jQuery. I've created some code but when I use `dd(value)` it turned out to be null. Is there any other way to get the slider value? Thanks.

```
$("#slider-range").slider({  
            range: true,
            min: min,
            max: max,
            values: [minPrice, maxPrice],
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                $("#amount_min").val(ui.values[0]);
                $("#amount_max").val(ui.values[1]);
            }, 
            change: function(event, ui) {
                var min = $("#amount_min").val();
                var max = $("#amount_max").val();
                var url = $(location).attr('href');
            
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {min:min, max:max, url:url},
                    success: function(data){
                        $('.filter_products').html(data);
                        console.log(min,max)
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        alert('error');
                    }
                })

            }
        });
```

Controller

```
$min = $request->min_price_min;
$max = $request->max_price_max;
     
if(isset($min) && !empty($min) && isset($max) && !empty($max)){
   $products->whereBetween('productprice', [$min, $max]);
}   
            
dd([$min, $max]);
```

View

```
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" id="amount_min" style="border:0; color:#d64d2f; font-weight:bold; width:100%;" class="minprice" name="min_price_min">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" id="amount_max" style="border:0; color:#d64d2f; font-weight:bold; width:100%;" class="maxprice text-right" name="max_price_max">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="slider-range" class="mx-2"></div>
```

Comment: You're sending properties named `min`, `max` and `url` in the AJAX request, yet your controller seems to be receiving `min_price_min` and `max_price_max`.

Comment: Also `var url = $(location).attr('href');` ??? Same page?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan, omg thankyou!!

Comment: @mplungjan yes, im throwing in the same page

Comment: I vote to close this as a typo-type question

Answer (score 0):

My mistakes.
Thanks to who replied.
I got wrong input (typo) in the controller, it should be `min` and `max` not `min_price_min` and `max_price_max`.